# AWK: How do I subtract the final field on those lines that have numbers

Tags: awk

I have a file containing:

```
A......Page 23
by John Smith
B......Page 73
by Jane Doe
C......Page 131
by Alice Grey
```

And I want to subtract the numbers by 22, so the first line will be `A......Page 1`.

I have searched in many places about gsub or any other awk option with no avail. I have done it through vim editor but knowing the awk solution will be great.

Comment: Good that you have told us that you have tried some code, it is always good to add that in your  post itself, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short `awk` approach:

```
$ awk '$NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/{ $NF = $NF-22 }1' file
A......Page 1
by John Smith
B......Page 51
by Jane Doe
C......Page 109
by Alice Grey
```

---

- `$NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/` - considering only lines which last field value `$NF` is a digit, as it is subjected to arithmetic operation

Comment: This answer is more concise but I have written down both in my notebook for the value they bring.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$NF=$NF~/[0-9]/ && $NF>22?$NF-22:$NF} 1'  Input_file
```

I have considered that you need NOT to have negative values in last column so I have checked condition if `$NF` last column is greater than `22` then only perform subtraction and then 2nd condition I considered that(which is obvious) that you want to subtract `22` with digits only so have put condition where it checks if last column is having digits in it or not.